# Code style quality. Should I upvote badly styled answers

Tags: discussion

I have been writing code for many decades and know one of the leading causes of bugs is bad and inconsistent code styling. When I teach programming, whatever the language I insist on consistent styling. I do not specify which style, that is up to the individual, it is consistency that is important.

There are many answers that I see here where the logic is sound but the code style is very bad. I just can not get myself to give an up vote, despite the fact that the answer is correct. I want to give a down vote for bad/inconsistently styled answers but I am not sure if that is considered good reason to down vote.

This is a place to learn and those that come here for answers are usually inexperienced and likely to pick up the styles people use in their answers.

What do I do.

- Up vote, its only the logic that counts?
- Down vote, style consistency is as important as logic?
- Do nothing and silently roll my eyes? as I have been doing.

Comment: Don't vote only based on the formatting of a post. There is an [edit] button, so everyone can improve the post.

Comment: By "bad" do you mean they indent by the 'wrong' number of spaces or "bad" as in "I had to read that 5 times before I could understand it"? Because if it's the latter, then I agree with Rizier123. If the formatting is an actual problem then fix it.

Comment: Which begets the bigger question: does a blind man ever roll his eyes?  Hmm.   Just click the Edit link, best to wait until you've got 3K rep btw.

Comment: @BSMP Bad is not the wrong number of spaces, it is using 4 spaces in function A and 3 in function B. Bad is using camel case and snake case in the same code without reason. Bad is placing a "{" at the end of a line at some places and on the next line at other places.

Comment: If the answer correctly answers the question with a working example, then I wouldn't downvote. Even if they use different indenting on every line, it's still valid code. Just edit the code formatting for consistency.

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean 2k rep?

Comment: @Klors Votes are there to indicate how useful a post is, not whether or not it is correct (although an incorrect post is *typically* not a useful post).  A correct post that is confusing, fails to properly convey the important information, is misleading, etc. *is not a useful answer*, even if it is factually correct.

Comment: @Servy as a user that has asked questions that have received zero attention despite being clearly asked and having bounties placed, I can happily tell you I would have voted up a correct answer written in alternating caps with a different indentation every line, then edited it for clarity, over receiving nothing. But in all honesty if it works, it's useful, and as such I wouldn't vote it down unless it was unreadable/indecipherable. Some slight inconsistencies don't sound like that to me. I probably wouldn't vote it up either. As I said, I'd just edit it.

Comment: @Klors The fact that a particular correct answer is also useful to you doesn't mean that all correct answers are useful, or that an answer is useful just because it's correct.  I've seen plenty of answer that were technically correct answers to the question, but that left people reading it completely unsure of what the actual answer to the question was, or worse still, thinking that they knew the answer when they actually didn't.  And if you're only concerned with the ability to copy-paste the code, without regard for the ability to understand it, then there's a bigger problem.

Comment: @Servy I agree, but given the examples that Blindman67 gave, I wouldn't regard them as degrading the usefulness of an example to the point of uselessness (ie. "Bad is not the wrong number of spaces, it is using 4 spaces in function A and 3 in function B. Bad is using camel case and snake case in the same code without reason. Bad is placing a "{" at the end of a line at some places and on the next line at other places")

Comment: How about you clean up the styling and correctly format it?

Comment: The thing that kills me is that most (?) modern editors will properly indent your code for you and yet I see a LOT of questions and answers not taking advantage of this. It's to the point where I just copy/paste into an IDE, hit a keyboard shortcut, maybe clean up a bit of the code or other formatting issues, copy/paste back into SO. It takes just a couple minutes and it's so much easier to read and understand.

Comment: I hate "ransom note" style in code. I have my own style preferences but I'm happy to tolerate other styles, as long as there is some consistency. FWIW, these days I mostly code in Python, where whitespace is syntactically significant so bad indentation can lead to syntax errors (if you're lucky) or incorrect execution (if you're not so lucky). That helps, to a degree, but you still see sloppy code in the Python tag.

Comment: Add a comment: _+1 if you correct your spelling, fix the formatting and add links to the relevant pages of documentation._

Comment: I think 95% of the code I've seen would fall under Blindman67's definition of "Bad"; the main problem being that real-world code is the product of several peoples' work over a number of years. Coding style is different for each programmer, or gets inherited from frameworks or libraries, or has been cut and pasted from places like StackExchange. I've even seen functions where half the variables have English names, and the other half Dutch. Idealism is great, but it's simply not productive to train everyone to one standard, or to refactor an entire codebase.

Comment: To me, "bad" code is code that has useless variable/function names, or is badly structured. If you see this in an answer, I would absolutely recommend refactoring, testing and posting it. The same goes if you see deprecated functions, or issues such potential unassigned pointers or division by zero. But for variable casing and bracket positioning I really don't care. If someone wants to refactor an answer to their own chosen coding standard then they have that option.

Comment: Well, @BenHillier, how about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/149099/1000608) :)

Comment: Indeed @aross. Quite unfortunate that 980 people have upvoted that!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Do nothing and silently roll my eyes? as I have been doing.

No, whatever you do, don't do that!

You're free to vote and/or moderate how you see fit.

You didn't mention leaving a comment. Because that offers you the option to explain how the style can be improved. I'm not sure if in that particular language/technology stack there is a common accepted style. If there is you can link to that.

However, I wouldn't try to enforce *your* style on the community, if other styles might work as well there should be room for those. You can also positively encourage good style practices, both with comments and/or up votes.

*(If you have edit privileges (>=2k rep) consider [the answer from Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308712/578411))*

Comment: Thank you. I would never down vote without a comment, personally I think that to be rude. Yes maybe i should comment on style inconsistency when I see it. I do not want to enforce a particular style, just style consistency within the answer.

Comment: That sounds great and valuable to visitors. Please start doing that @Blindman67

Comment: Yes, if it's bad, I leave a comment.  There is no point wasting time trying to unravel code if there are other questions with text that is easily readable.  If we can't easily read it, the chances are that the OP could not follow it well either and has done little, or no, debugging.  Comment, downvote, next question.

Answer (score 20):

Interestingly enough, neither you nor the nearest answer mention *editing* the answer to bring it in line with a better standard.  To be blunt, editing the answer may be a better approach, since:

- It allows for clarity in the answer
- It improves its readability and accessibility
- It's virtually painless to do, provided you have a decent IDE/editor and are careful not to introduce errors through your styling (I'm looking at you, Python)

I agree in that [you shouldn't enforce your own style on anyone else](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308707/1079354), but it would make sense to format the response of the code at least in the same style as the question is asked (if its style is acceptable).

**If you don't yet have the ["Edit Questions and Answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege**, then be sure that any edits you do also contain other fixes, such as grammar, or sentence structure.  Be sure to leave reasons why you edited the post as well in case a prospective reviewer has a knee-jerk reaction to reject because it *only* improved code style.

Comment: Well, it sounds nice, but kinda invites: 'Hmm my code now mostly works, but it's a bit of a mess and I haven't time to clean... ohwait..I'll just post it to SO and go down teh bar; some slave will clean it up before submission deadline!

Comment: @MartinJames: Personally I don't take that mindset or attitude when I go through and code format others' work.  In fact, I *completely* divorce whatever mindset they *may* have when they wrote the answer away from the answer itself, so I'm not sure I could agree with your rationale.  Personally I've never run into this scenario, but if you do notice a pattern of a certain user posting sloppy code, it's worth commenting to that effect, but I personally wouldn't read much more into it.

Comment: @Martin is right. We have a _responsibility_ not to spoon feed, Makoto.

Comment: I'm with all of the above comments. Never know who is on the receiving end of it. I believe many people that put sloppy posts up, and I certainly did in the beginning, have no clue of the importance of styling, blocking, authoritative references. I would have been happy to receive a notification of an edit, did, and would have learned something from it, as opposed to thinking some janitor will clean up from behind

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  I personally don't see how it's spoon-feeding, but to each their own.  I have my opinion on it and I personally will continue to edit those posts for style.  I don't do it because I get any impression that the person is lazy; I do it because I *also* stumble upon it and believe that it'd fare better if the formatting were cleaned up a bit.  No one's forcing anyone to edit the content, and if one elects not to, that's their decision.

Comment: @Makoto: I sometimes edit it too. But I do at least ask the OP to spend a little time learning to do it themselves, first. Eventually I might give up or, in the case that quite a long time has passed, it's clear the OP's not going to bother so then it simply becomes a case of quality control. Everything in moderation, I guess is what I'm saying, with teaching/training being a factor to consider amongst the rest.

Answer (score 14):

At the end of the day votes are there to indicate whether or not the post is useful.

Are the problems with the style of the code so bad that *the post ceases to be useful*?  It's certainly possible that the problems are so severe that the code fails to properly convey important information necessary to answer the question, or that the odds of it confusing readers enough to cause bugs is sufficiently high as to result in it having a net harm.  If you really feel that the problems are that bad, then you should downvote.

If the style of the post detracts from its value a bit, but not so much that the post is causing a net harm, then you shouldn't be downvoting it.